# Getting ModuleNotFound error while importing from same subdirectory

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror

Unable to import str from a module in the same directory.

Project is structured like this:

```
parent   
└───cmds
    └───chat_client.py
        auth_client.py
```

In `chat_client.py` when I try to `from cmds.auth_client import sesuser` I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmds'`.

I tried removing the `cmds.` part, however instead it just gave me `ImportError: cannot import name 'sesuser' from 'auth_client' (e:\parent\cmds\auth_client.py)`.

Comment: Just use:  from auth_client.py import sesuser

Comment: Tried that and got `ImportError: cannot import name 'sesuser' from 'auth_client' (e:\parent\cmds\auth_client.py)`

Answer (score 0):

```
from auth_client import sesuser
```

try removing  extention '.py'

Comment: Edited the question, wasn't using .py, accidentally put it in the question.

Comment: check if the problem is circular import. https://www.oneworldcoders.com/apprentice-journals/python-circular-imports

Comment: It's not, nothing in auth_client tried to import anything from chat_client.